# Cadlag function, metric

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes

Please to meet you. I have a question about a càdlàg function and its space.

[Ma & Röckner's book (page 93)](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/probability/book/978-3-540-55848-4) contains the following metric space $(\mathcal{D},d)$.

Let $E$ be a complete separable metric space equipped with a bounded metric $\rho$.
A function $a$ from $[0,\infty]$ to $E$ is called **càdlàg** if $t \mapsto a(t)$ is right continuous on $[0,\infty]$ and has left limits $a(t-)$ for all $t \in[0,\infty]$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the set of all càdlàg functions from $[0,\infty]$ to $E$. Let $\Lambda$ be the set of all $\mathbb{R}$-valued increasing functions $\lambda$ such that $\lambda(0)=0$. For $\lambda \in \Lambda$ define
\begin{align*}
\|\lambda\|:=\sup_{s,t \geq0 ,s\neq t} \left| \log\frac{\lambda(t)-\lambda(s)}{t-s} \right|+\sup_{t \geq 0} \left|\lambda(t)-t \right|
\end{align*} 
For $a,b \in \mathcal{D}$ define 
\begin{align*}
d(a,b)=\inf \left\{ \|\lambda\|+\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(a(t),b(\lambda(t))) : \lambda \in \Lambda \right\}
\end{align*}

If $\|\lambda\|<\infty$, we can see $\lambda$ is continuous, strictly increasing and onto. In this case for its inverse $\lambda^{-1}(\in \Lambda)$ that $\|\lambda^{-1}\|=\|\lambda\|$. If $\|\lambda_{1}\|,\|\lambda_{2}\|<\infty$ then $\lambda_{1}\circ\lambda_{2}\in \Lambda,\,\|\lambda_{1}\circ \lambda_{2}\|\leq \|\lambda_{1}\|+\|\lambda_{2}\|$

**I want to show $(\mathcal{D},d)$ is a metric space.**

But I have a hard time with showing 
$d(a,b)=d(b,a), d(a,c) \leq d(a,b)+d(a,c)\quad(a,b,c \in \mathcal{D})$

My process

$d(a,b)=d(b,a)$:

It is enough to show that for $\lambda \in \Lambda  $ such that $\|\lambda\|<\infty$ (in this case $\lambda,\lambda^{-1}:[0,\infty]\to [0,\infty]$ is bijective), \begin{align*}
\|\lambda\|+\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(a(t),b(\lambda(t))) &=\|\lambda^{-1}\|+\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(a(\lambda^{-1}(t)),b(t))
\end{align*}
I already know $\|\lambda^{-1}\|=\|\lambda\|$. But I don't know how to prove $\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(a(t),b(\lambda(t))) =\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(a(\lambda^{-1}(t)),b(t))
$

---

**ADD**

I think $\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(a(t),b(\lambda(t)))=\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-\lambda^{-1}(t)} \rho(a(\lambda^{-1}(t)),b(t)) $ is clear.

---

$d(a,b)\leq d(a,c)+d(c,b)$:

For $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2} \in \Lambda  $ such that $\|\lambda_{1}\|,\| \lambda_{2}\|<\infty$, we have 
\begin{align*}
&\|\lambda_{1}\circ\lambda_{2}\|+\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(a(t),b(\lambda_{1}\circ \lambda_{2}(t)))\\
 &\leq \|\lambda_{1}\|+\|\lambda_{2}\|+\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(a(t),b(\lambda_{1}\circ \lambda_{2}(t)))\\
&\leq \left(\|\lambda_{2}\|+\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(a(t),c(\lambda_{2}(t)))\right)+\left(\|\lambda_{1}\|
 +\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(c(\lambda_{2}(t)),b(\lambda_{1}\circ \lambda_{2}(t))) \right)
\end{align*}
This means
\begin{align*}
d(a,b)
&\leq \left(\|\lambda_{2}\|+\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(a(t),c(\lambda_{2}(t)))\right)+\left(\|\lambda_{1}\|
 +\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(c(\lambda_{2}(t)),b(\lambda_{1}\circ \lambda_{2}(t))) \right)
\end{align*}
But I don't know how to prove

$\|\lambda_{1}\|
 +\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(c(t),b(\lambda_{1}(t))=\| \lambda_{1}\|
 +\sup_{t \geq 0}e^{-t} \rho(c(\lambda_{2}(t)),b(\lambda_{1}\circ \lambda_{2}(t))) $

Is there something good way? Thank you in advance.